# A problem about invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need help with the following problem:

> Let  $H\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be a plane with cartesian equation $x=y,$ and let  $r$ be the straight line generated by $(1,1,2)$.
>   Find an endomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\phi(\mathbb R^3)=H$ and $\phi^2(\mathbb R^3)=r$.

Is there a standard way to choose such endomorphism $\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend $v_1 = (1,1,2)$ to a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $H$ and then to a basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Take the endomorphism $\phi$ which maps $v_3$ to $v_2$, $v_2$ and $v_1$ to $v_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\text{Range}(\phi)=H, \ \phi(H)=r,
$$
and 
$$
H=\{(x,y,z):\ x=y\}=\text{span}\{(1,1,0), \ (0,0,1)\}, \ r=\text{span}\{(1,1,2)\},
$$
if we denote by $A$ of $\phi$ with respect to the canonical basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we have 
$$
A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\cr
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\cr
b_1 & b_2 & b_3
\end{array}
\right],
$$
with
$$
b_1+b_2=2(a_1+a_2), \ b_3=2a_3.
$$
Thus the matrix $A$ of $\phi$ has the form
$$
A=A(a,b,c,d)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\cr
a & b & c\cr
d & 2(a+b)-d & 2c
\end{array}
\right],
$$
provided $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is such that $A(a,b,c,d) \ne 0$.